# How can I wrap a line at 80 characters in Markdown?

Tags: markdown

I'm writing a basic README.md for documentation at my company.

I'd like to wrap each line of text at 80 characters, but I really don't know how. At present, it just extends all the way to the right of the page.

Do I need a table?

I'd ideally not like to modify each separate line. Is there any way to wrap an entire paragraph?

Comment: FYI many devices are less than 80 characters wide - phones may be less, even Unix is often 72 characters wide. Is there a specific need to add carriage returns after every 80 characters for every reader, rather than just set whatever you preferred width is during editing?

Comment: **Wrapping at 80 characters will break most devices, including mobile devices, many Unix terminals (that usually wrap at 78 characters to display other terminal elements), and more.** Leave display of your markdown to the display device, which will format it according to the user's screen.

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/questions/610903/how-to-unwrap-80-character-text

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p), you just need to type a double space followed by a carriage return. Most modern text editors will let you know what column you're on.

The quickest, easiest way to do this is use Notepad++. Select the text you wish to wrap and use the menu option *TextFX* -> *TextFX Edit* -> *ReWrap Text to (Clipboard or 72) Width*.

Comment: I'm still not clear. If I try pressing space twice and then "Enter" after a line, there seems to be no effect.

Comment: There is no special formatting for hard-wrapped text in markdown. You just double space and hit enter at 80 characters.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do anything for me. I feel like I'm missing something obvious. line of text space space enter leaves it the same.

Comment: Modified the question to ask for solutions at the paragraph instead of line level. Adding an explicit <br /> tag works, but if I ever want to add anything, I have to modify everything. Is there any way around that?

Comment: Interesting. This only works when there's not tags. But the moment I try using <h1> somewhere, it stops working. Any clue why?

Comment: I'll try and reproduce it, but the content of your readme would be helpful.

Comment: Yessir. Here's a sample. Line 1: <h1> Sample </h1> Line 2: <p> I like cats. Everything continues to right edge of webpage instead of wrapping the way I've formatted it, oh no! Is there a solution? </p>

Answer (score 1):

> When you do want to insert a 
>  break tag using Markdown, you end
>   a line with two or more spaces, then type return.  -[Daring Fireball](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/syntax#p)

So, you can look at your editor's display and when you are at column 80, type two spaces, and then type return.

Comment: Modified the question to ask for solutions at the paragraph instead of line level. Adding an explicit <br /> tag works, but if I ever want to add anything, I have to modify everything. Is there any way around that?

Answer (score -1):

A simple hack using clang-format:

Install clang-format(if not already installed)

```
sudo apt-get install clang-format
```

Generate clang-format file(if not already present)

```
clang-format -style=llvm -dump-config > .clang-format
```

Copy contents of .md file and paste it in a new file, save this newly created file with extension .cpp. Mark pasted content of .md file as a C++ comment by encapsulating it with `/*` and `*/`

Use created clang-format file as,

```
clang-format -i foo.cpp
```

where foo is the name of saved C++ file.

You can now uncomment contents of original .md file and use it.

Note:

This works due to the following property of clang-format file

```
ColumnLimit:     80
```